# Deja de funcionar el archivo.exe

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un simulador de blackjack pero al momento de compilar el archivo .exe deja de funcionar, mostrando la consola vacía. Dejo el main por si esta ahí el problema.

```
int main(){  
Baraja *Inglesa;
Jugador *Jugador1;
Jugador *Jugador2;
Crupier *crupier;
int a=0;
int b=0;
int c=0;
Inglesa->barajar();
cout<<"Bienvenidos al Blackjack"<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
    a = Inglesa->robar()->getNumero() + a;
    b = Inglesa->robar()->getNumero() + b;
    c = Inglesa->robar()->getNumero() + c;  
}
Jugador1->setPuntaje(a);
Jugador2->setPuntaje(b);
crupier->setPuntaje(c);

cout<<"Jugador 1 tu puntaje inicial es: "<<Jugador1->getPuntaje()<<endl;
Jugador1->Jugar(Inglesa);
cout<<"Jugador 2 tu puntaje inicial es: "<<Jugador2->getPuntaje()<<endl;
Jugador2->Jugar(Inglesa);
crupier->Jugar(Inglesa);

if(Jugador1->getPuntaje() > Jugador2->getPuntaje() && Jugador1->getPuntaje() > crupier->getPuntaje() )
{
    cout<<"El Jugador 1 es el ganador!";
}
if(Jugador2->getPuntaje() > Jugador1->getPuntaje() && Jugador2->getPuntaje() > crupier->getPuntaje() )
{
    cout<<"El Jugador 2 es el ganador!";
}
else{
    cout<<"Gana la mesa";
}

return 0;}
```

Comment: Explica eso de "deja de funcionar"... para "dejar de funcionar" tiene que haber funcionado en algún momento, lo hace? Cuando "deja de funcionar", que hace? Compila? al ejecutarlo, arroja algún error?  Sobre tu código, te falta el caso donde ambos jugadores tienen un puntaje igual, mayor al crupier, ganan ambos.

Comment: Literal deja de funcionar. Me aparece el mensaje de "Blackjack.exe" a dejado de funcionar. A todo esto, el compilador es dev-c++ puse la etiqueta pero no sé que sucedió que no aparece. Ahh y sí, compila, no me aparece ningún mensaje de error en el compilador mismo.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main() {
  Baraja *Inglesa; // 1

  // ...

  Inglesa->barajar(); // 2

  // ...
```

En 1 estás declarando un puntero y en 2 lo usas como si nada... ¿a dónde apunta ese puntero? Antes de usar cualquier tipo de variable hay que incializarla:

```
Baraja *Inglesa = new Baraja;
```

Aunque viendo tu programa no tiene demasiado sentido usar punteros aquí. Esto simplificaría bastante ya que se podría invocar al constructor de forma implícita:

```
Baraja inglesa; // El constructor se invoca implicitamente
```

Y, por supuesto, si optas por seguir usando punteros no olvides liberar la memoria antes de salir del programa:

```
delete Inglesa;
```

**Nota:** Lo que te comento sobre inicializar los punteros es igualmente aplicable a `Jugador1`, `Jugador2` y `crupier`